# react-native production undefined is not a function error

Tags: react-native

I developed an app, and released it to Google Play. After a while, I started get production error reports, which contains this errors:

```
TypeError: s.generateNewNodeTag is not a function. (In 's.generateNewNodeTag()', 's.generateNewNodeTag' is an instance of Object)
```

and

```
 Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: TypeError: c.API.disconnectAnimatedNodes is not a function. (In 'c.API.disconnectAnimatedNodes(this.__getNativeTag(),t.__getNativeTag())', 'c.API.disconnectAnimatedNodes' is an instance of Object)
```

Looks like all errors comes from core of react-native, but I can;t actually realize a reason, why this errors happen. This errors come from very small % of users, and I can't reproduce them locally.

RN version is 0.59.9